# Special combinations with score in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, combinations, graph-algorithm

I have k time intervals that calls epochs (e.g Epoch1, Epoch2,.., Epochk). I have a set **S** of n elements (e.g A, B, C, D, E, F).

I have to assign to each epoch an elemnt of powerset(S) but every elements in powerset(S) have a score 
that depends on epoch.

For example A in Epoch1 have score = 5, but in Epoch2 have score = 4.

I need to assign for all epochs an element of the powerset(S), but there is a problem. I have another global score that is the sum of all epochs score minus the number of change between contiguos epochs multiplied by a parameter lambda.

For example if i have:

```
Epoch1 = AB with score 5;
Epoch2 = A with score 6;
Epoch3= C with score 4
```

I have one change betwenn Epoch1 and Epoch2 (remove B), two change between Epoch3 and Epoch2 (remove A and add c), then the global score is 6+5+4 - 3*lambda.

For this reason i can't get the maximum of each epochs. 
One solutions is to make all combination, but if |S| = 30, |powerset(30)| = 2^30, i suppose we have C'(2^30, k) combinations with repetitions.

There is a method for get the maximum without compute all combination ?

Comment: How are the scores for each of the subsets of S for each epoch calculated? Sure, you are not just given 2^30 * (number-of-epochs) values. If there is some system in these values, perhaps it would help come to an efficient solution.

Answer (score 0):

My idea for an algorithm that finds local optima:

Treat your Epoch configurations as one long string, then use a genetic algorithm to find a local optimum of the configuration.

I feel you are making the problem too hard, instead of viewing the problem as "find the best Set of sets E1{A,B,C....}, E2{...} etc., see everything as one big set E{A1,B1,A2,C3}, then try to find the maximum over that space. As i said, a genetical algorithm might work ok.

Maybe with that view you can model this differently, maybe as linear mixed integer optimization problem if the relations between the variables and the scores can be expressed in such a way. If you can model it in such a way, then you can get a globally optimal result. I can't help more with the modeling though, since you didn't say how you compute the Epoch score.

Comment: The problem is i need the globally optimal result. I can find a local optimal simply with the max score for each epochs. The computation score regards a complex arguments that I can't explain in a simple way here.
Why see everything as one big set is more simple?

Comment: Well maybe i understood the problem wrong. You score decreases when you have lots of changes, so how can you be sure max score of each epoch is locally optimal? Seeing everything as a single set is imho simpler because instead of n scoring functions you end up with exactly one (which might be more complex though). I guess it's a matter of taste, but for using a genetical algorithm it would be easier because you can then model your sequence of epochs as a single binary string that you can just stuff in your algorithm.

Comment: Yes, if I have a more change the global score on all  epochs decrease. But with genetic algorithms I can get better results than the local maxima for each time? Where i can get more information with this kind of algorithms? I suppose that aspire to the global maximum, in these conditions, isn't it possible?

Comment: I don't want to say that it's not possible, but i would guess there are lots of local optima, so finding the global optimum reliably might not be possible. Algorithms like genetic algorithms or simulated annealing help escape local optima though (i don't really have much experience with those algorithms)